# How To Get Value From An Object Inside An Array In My Angular Application

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

So I have this array of object coming from an API in my Angular Application

```
"register":[
{
"club": 8,
"players": 100,
"officials": 10
},
{
"male": 7,
"female": 2,
"other": 1
},
{
"Brazil": 5,
"France": 1,
"Italy": 2,
"England": 2
}
]
```

My aim is to display an item in the third object on the console. So I tried looping through the array of object this way:

```
 let country =  data['register'].map(data => data.England)
  console.log(country) // Output: [undefined, undefined, 2]
```

I guess the **undefined** are coming from the first two objects.

How do I loop through this object to get only the figure for **England** in the third Object, without the first two **undefined** showing?

**Note**:

**data** is coming from the API I subscribed to in the **.ts** file. It contains all the results from the API.

Comment: `data['register'][2].England` if the position of the element is always the 3rd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.filter()` out all objects which don't have a `England` key (and keep all those which do) and then `.map()` your array of objects like so:

```js
const data = {register:[{club:8,players:100,officials:10},{male:7,female:2,other:1},{Brazil:5,France:1,Italy:2,England:2}]};

let country = data.register
                 .filter(obj => 'England' in obj) // keep all objects in your array with the England property
                 .map(obj => obj.England) // map to the england property

console.log(country) // Output: [2]
```

If `England` can never have a value of `0`, you can `.filter()` after mapping by using `Boolean()` like so:

```js
const data = {register:[{club:8,players:100,officials:10},{male:7,female:2,other:1},{Brazil:5,France:1,Italy:2,England:2}]};

const country = data.register.map(({England}) => England).filter(Boolean);
console.log(country) // Output: [2]
```

---

**EDIT:** As per your question in the comments, if you wish to get the number value of each property into an array, you can use `.flatMap` with `Object.values()`:

```js
const data = {register:[{club:8,players:100,officials:10},{male:7,female:2,other:1},{Brazil:5,France:1,Italy:2,England:2}]};

let country = data.register
                 .filter(obj => 'England' in obj) // keep all objects in your array with the England property
                 .flatMap(Object.values) // flatMap the array returned by Object.values

console.log(country) // Output: [5, 1, 2, 2]
```

Or with lodash (more browser compatible):

```js
const data = {register:[{club:8,players:100,officials:10},{male:7,female:2,other:1},{Brazil:5,France:1,Italy:2,England:2}]};

const englandObjects = _.filter(data.register, obj => 'England' in obj) 
const numberVals = _.flatMap(englandObjects, Object.values);

console.log(numberVals);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This worked.

Also, If I were to display all the elements in the object as an array. How would I go about that?

I tired doing this:
```
let country = data.register
                 .filter(obj => 'England' in obj).map(obj => obj) 

console.log(country) // Output: [{"Brazil": 5,"France": 1,"Italy": 2,"England": 2}]
```

I just want them to be in an array and not an array of object. Something like this:

```
[5,1, 2, 2]

Answer (score 2):

you can use `_.compact(array)` built-in function from Lodash which removes all the falsy values like false, null, 0, "", undefined and NaN.

```
let country = _.compact(data['register'].map(data => data.England));
console.log(country) // Output: [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use case of map is totally different than what you are trying to achieve. Map iterates over your collections and for each item under collections, produce new result and will be returned that. So for first two object it not finding so **Undefined**. You have 3 object, you got array of 3 with first two being **undefined** Use map when you want to process collections and wants new collection with your desired result.

Here you can use find :

```
const foundItem = data.register.find(item => item.England)
console.log(foundItem.England); // you can access all attributes here
console.log( [foundItem.England] ); // as array
```

Comment: The issue I had with .find() was, it was giving me the results as an object. I wanted it as an array.

Comment: just assign as array :    console.log( [ foundItem.England ] ); i edited

Comment: This works well too, but for the scenario I'm facing,  I'll be going with Nick Parsons answer Above. i really appreciate your response. Thanks.

Comment: @DejiAdesoga No worries.